# How to avoid user being able to create a Double Booking in a database?

Tags: c#, winforms, datetime

Basically I would like to stop my system from allowing the user to be able to create multiple bookings under the same time slot for a booking if that makes sense. My system basically allows a user to make a booking for a walk, and ideally each walk should only be able to be booked from Monday to Sunday during working hours, but a slot should be 1.5 hours each but at the moment, there is no slots, just the date time pickers for the time and date of the booking and for multiple bookings the user can just pick the same time so i do want to get that fixed.

Hopefully this helps- I have attached my code for my "add booking" form so hopefully thats of some use.

```
public partial class AddBooking : Form
{
    private int count;
    private Boolean IsEmpty = false;
    private static string _connectionstring = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DoggieConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    
    public AddBooking()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        CenterToScreen();
        GenerateBookingNumber();
        IDDisplay.Text = "" + count;
        dateTimePicker2.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
        dateTimePicker2.CustomFormat = "HH:mm tt";
        dateTimePicker2.ShowUpDown = true;
        DateTime now = DateTime.Now;

    }

    private void AddBooking_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private int GenerateBookingNumber()
    {
        string smt = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dbo.Booking";
        count = 0;

        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(_connectionstring))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmdCount = new SqlCommand(smt, connection))
            {
                connection.Open();
                count = (int)Convert.ToInt32(cmdCount.ExecuteScalar());
            }
        }
        count = count + 4;
        return count;
    }

    private void PresenceCheck()
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(WalkLocationtxt.Text) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(StaffIDtxt.Text))
        {
            IsEmpty = true;
        }
        else
        {
            IsEmpty = false;
        }
    }

    private void SubmitInfobtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       // MessageBox.Show("welcome " + dateTimePicker1.Value.ToShortDateString());
       // MessageBox.Show("Goodddd" + dateTimePicker2.Value.ToShortTimeString());
        PresenceCheck();
        
       

        if (IsEmpty == false)
        {
            int rowsareaffected = ClassDatabase.AddBookingDetails(Convert.ToInt32(IDDisplay.Text), dateTimePicker1.Value.ToShortDateString(), dateTimePicker2.Value.ToShortTimeString(), Convert.ToInt32(StaffIDtxt.Text), WalkLocationtxt.Text);

            if (rowsareaffected > 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("New Booking Added Sucessfully", "Sucess!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                
                StaffIDtxt.Clear();
                WalkLocationtxt.Clear();
                

                GenerateBookingNumber();

                IDDisplay.Text = "" + count;
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("An Error Occurred", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        }
    }

    private void dateTimePicker2_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      

    }

    private void mENUToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void returnToMenuToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        new MenuScreen().Show();
        this.Close();
    }

    private void logOutToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        new LoginScreen().Show();
        this.Close();
    }

    private void exitSystemToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DialogResult Result = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to Exit the JD Dog Care Program?", "Are You Sure?", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Hand);
        if (Result == DialogResult.Yes)
        {
            Application.Exit();
        }
        else
        {

        }
    }

    private void addClientToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        new AddClient().Show();
        this.Close();
    }

    private void manageClientsToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        new ViewClient().Show();
        this.Close();
    }

    private void addDogsToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        new AddDog().Show();
        this.Close();
    }

    private void manageDogsToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        new ViewDog().Show();
        this.Close();
    }

    private void addStaffToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        new AddStaff().Show();
        this.Close();
    }

    private void manageStaffToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        new ViewStaff().Show();
        this.Close();
    }

    private void addBookingToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        new AddBooking().Show();
        this.Close();
    }

    private void manageBookingToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        new ViewBooking().Show();
        this.Close();
    }

    private void addDogToBookingToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        new DogToWalk().Show();
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: And what code do you have so far to do that? By the way you shouldn't use `count(*)` to generate IDs, use an `IDENTITY` column instead

Comment: @Charlieface I haven't got any code so far for it as I am not sure as to how to do it- I am not sure what an IDENTITY column is either, a lot of this was not learnt in the classroom, I tried my best with the coursework over lockdown but it is hard when not with others to bounce ideas of. Bear in mind this is an A level project and doesn't have to be amazing, but I do want to polish up on a few things

Comment: You need to give us code to work with, the code above is just a dump of your project but doesn't show how you want achieve prevention of double-booking. We have no idea your tables and PK/FK relationships, no idea even how you want to enforce this, is it a database constraint, an error show in the user interface, what? We can't write a whole program for you. `IDENTITY` see https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql-identity-property?view=sql-server-ver15 also you shouldn't pass through dates as string `ToShortDateString` instead add together your date ....

Comment: .... and time components and pass them through as `DateTime` values

Comment: @Charlieface I understand, and I don't expect anyone to write my code, I was just looking some guidance as to how to prevent a double booking. Pretty much if i can get this form figured out which is the code above, then I should be able to carry over to the other forms. The fields are Booking ID (The primary key) , date of the walk,  time of the walk, StaffID (which is a FK linking to the staff table, and Walk location. I need to be able to prevent the user from being able to select the same time for a walk if a walk already exists during that time, and ideally, i would like the time selector

Comment: to have increments of 1 and a half hour slots , to allow each walk this time frame, so that when a user selects a time, the same time cant be selected again, and therefor prevents a double booking, Just a bit lost on how to accomplish this though.

Comment: and an error showing in the UI on the actual windows form would be sufficient - just a simple message box to show to the user saying that a walk already exists for that time slot and to try again... Just dont know the SQL statements or command to check against the table and the time value being entered if that makes sense

Comment: You probably want some kind of `IF EXISTS` or `SELECT COUNT` statement. If you want to physically prevent that time from even being selected you would have to select back all the existing data for that day, store it somewhere and use it in validation, which might be more trouble than it's worth

Comment: @Charlieface Okay thanks, think ill leave out the disabling it from being selected and focus on having a statement to actually just show an error if the user tries to select a time that already exists. I'll give that a go- Thanks again for your help.